# RecyclerView к списку элементов

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Проблема следующего характера, создал список checkBox-ов при помощи recyclerView, наполняю его следующим образом:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ManufactureListAdapter.MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
    final String item = listManufactured.get(i);

    myViewHolder.cbItem.setText(item);
    myViewHolder.cbItem.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                checkedManufactureList.add(item);
            } else {
                checkedManufactureList.remove(item);
            }
        }
    });

    onCheckedListListener.checkedListListener(checkedManufactureList);
}
```

Мне нужно выполнять сброс всех checkBox по кнопке или иному событию из вызывающего класса, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте для `item` свой класс `Item`, который будет иметь переменную `checked`, `name` и другие переменные, необходимые для работы приложения.

Типа так:

```
public class Item {
    private boolean checked;
    private String name;

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }   

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }  

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    } 

}
```

При нажатии на кнопку делаете вот так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) 
      items.get(i).setChecked(false);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

При этом в `onBindViewHolder` у вас в обязательном порядке должно быть:

```
myViewHolder.cbItem.setChecked(item.getChecked());
```

Comment: _P.S._ к тому же `String` в java не расширяемый (`final`)

Comment: Спасибо, я никогда не рассматривал объекты в таком вот виде использования, а зря.Теперь буду. Исправьте пожалуйста расширение класса String и выделите последний абзац (P.S.), он проясняет что нужно сделать с классом, так будет людям легче понять, вдруг если кому понадобится.

Comment: учёл замечания, исправил ответ :)