# Создание списка с checkbox

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment

изучаю android и такой вопрос - хочу создать activity, на котором будет отображаться список определенных продуктов с checkbox, и человек будет листать список и отмечать ту продукцию, которая ему нужна. Мне для этого нужно изучить ListView, Fragment ? Увидел еще про некий baseAdapter и я не знаю что нужно мне.

Comment: изучите `RecyclerView` и адаптер к нему. В качестве `ViewHolder` - вью с текстом+чекбоксом, в качестве данных - `ArrayList<Product>` (где `Product` - ваш класс, в котором будет имя и состояние (отмечено/нет) и что-нибудь еще). Посмотрите, тут на что-то подобное отвечал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/895829/recyclerview-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2/895837#895837

Comment: да, вам надо будет изучить много интересных вещей, чтобы сделать такой список